# WPF Validation using IDataErrorInfo - How to remove duplicate Validation.ErrorTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I am doing validation of all text boxes using `IDataErrorInfo` on my WPF form like this:

```
<TextBox Name="txtAddress" 
         Validation.Error="Validation_Error"
         Text="{Binding Path=Address, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">

// If I have many TextBoxes to validate, I have to copy this and paste 
// for each TextBox in XAML.  This obviously violates DRY.  How do I define
// this at one place and use it for all TextBoxes on my form?
    <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
                <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" CornerRadius="10"
                    ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    <TextBlock Text="!" 
                               VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white"/>
                </Border>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Validation.ErrorTemplate>

</TextBox>
```

This is my Validation_Error method used above:

```
private void Validation_Error(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
    {
        mNumErrors++;
    }
    else
    {
        mNumErrors--;
    }
}
```

If I have many Textboxes on my form, I have to copy the  section above into each TextBox definition in XAML.  How do I define it on one place and use it for all TextBoxes?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

**1 Way**. You can move `ControlTemplate` to the Resources of application or window. And add into textBoxes `StaticResource` like this.

`ControlTemplate` in Resources with `x:Key` property.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
        <Border Background="Red" DockPanel.Dock="right" Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="16" Height="16" CornerRadius="10"
                                ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=customAdorner, Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
            <TextBlock Text="!" VerticalAlignment="center" HorizontalAlignment="center" 
                                FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="white"/>
        </Border>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="customAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="5" />
        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

`TextBox` with assigned `ErrorTemplate`.

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource MyErrorTemplate}" />
```

**2 Way**. If all TextBoxes should contain this `ErrorTemplate` you can define TextBox `Style` in the resources and add `ErrorTemplate` into it. The `Style` will be applied to all TextBoxes.

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                ...             
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks but if adding validation through Style like you are suggesting, I get "MyErrorTemplate could not be resolved".

Comment: You can add `ControlTemplate` into the `Style` setter directly, if it used only in the textBoxes. Or you can move `ControlTemplate` into app resources and style into window resources.

Comment: it is used only for TextBoxes and I tried exactly as you suggested above. It errors with ""MyErrorTemplate could not be resolved"

Comment: Edited the answer. You can add into `Style` without x:Key. With using style you should not specify textBoxes `Validation.ErrorTemplate`.